# Orbot (Tor) refusing SOCKS connection at port 9050

Tags: android, sockets, tor, orbot

I have app that is connecting to orbot socks proxy on port 9050. It worked till today but now it looks like this port is blocked. If I try to connect it my socket gets closed and I get stream closed exception. However if I change port on both Orbot and in my app to 9060 than it all works.

So I think that orbot is somehow blocking connection on port 9050. Is it possible that there is some old, non properly ended socket still blocking port 9050? If so, is there a way to remove it and make it working again? Restarting device didnt work.

Thanks in forward

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this, 
there was a problem with Samsung link service running on background. It was always listening on port 9050 and it was starting on boot so it was blocking port 9050 which couldnt be accessed by orbot.

Solution is to use SockStat app for example and check which services are listening on port. Then you need to turn off (disable) all apps listening on 9050 excepting orbot. Then it works.

Or you can change orbot Socks port to different